# cannot restore database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2019

whenever I try to restore a database I got an error message

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE
> failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed
> your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

because I am using SQL server express edition and the database size is more than 10GB.

I have the backup file only and I do not have access to reduce the data files

BTW data files are 20GBs.

is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Developer Edition is a free, unlimited edition of SQL Server for Development and Test purposes.  You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Not with SQL Express. Sign up for a Visual Studio subscription (free) and you can get a fully functional copy of SQL Server.

https://visualstudio.com/